# Can't select the actual object

Tags: transforms, transform-orientation

i have no idea what did i do, i can't select objects anymore well i still can select the object, however everytime i tried to transform it a yellow dot appeared and i just can transform the yellow dot. On the transform tab the object is 'transforming' however i don't see any difference i can't move scale or rotate the object, it feels like the object is represented by the yellow dot. sorry for the poor explanation, english is not my first language. here's a screenshot. the tv is the object i want to move, the yellow dot moves instead the tv is completely still

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have accidentally enabled the *Affect Only Origins* option (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>):

[image]

If enabled, you can only move the objects' origin.